# Why not use Gradient div's in web?

Tags: css, styling

Use of gradient images is very common among developers for styling a page. Gradient images are used in many places from styling the navigation bar to styling the background. Technique like repeating a small image in either direction is also common.

One more way to style and give this effect is by using multiple div's one below another with different color, the latter being a little lighter than the former. In the most simple scenario doing so would include only a small script. So, no problem of writing a lot of markup, just some simple code.

The only concern that remains is speed and performance.

**Speed**

The script, more precisely the function would be much shorter in size than a image. So, in matters of speed the latter method seems more good.

**Performance**

Today's browsers are very powerful, so the difference between displaying an image and executing a function is negligible.

**Css management**

Obviously, problems like positioning would be another concern but we do struggle with such problems in every day life. The problem is no greater than overlapping two div's and setting their z-index. The whole gradient div's can lie inside one parent div.

So having addressed the issues of performance and speed isn't using Gradient div's a much better approach than using images?

Comment: If you rely on JavaScript what happens to the users with JavaScript disabled?

Comment: So? If javascript is disabled use normal approach. Really how many users have javascript disabled, 10%? and this approach is definitely not for mobile browsers because its clear that this method is using javascript. @Sam its an alternate solution to using gradient images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an alternate approach, yes. But not a good one. You get zero points for:

- Maintainability
- Scalability
- SEO
- Separation of presentation from content

Furthermore, to say that we needn't worry about performance since today's browsers are more powerful is a gross assumption.

Comment: As I understand it, the general principle is that pages with more semantic markup are also indexed better. This becomes more true as search engines develop.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I think the second option you describe (creating multiple divs with atering colour) is downright terrible.

1. You're altering markup for the sake of styling. That's a no-go.
2. It's a common thing among users to disable JavaScript. What happens then?
3. As you said yourself, positioning mayhem.
4. When it comes to performance, I would be more cautious than to state it's no longer an issue. Especially with the dawn of mobile browsers in mind.
5. Such styling would be harder to understand and maintain. Particularly when your team changes someday.

Also, there are two other ways to implement gradients.

1. CSS gradients - limited to simple variants and requiring a lot of CSS to provide decent cross-browser capabilities. You can try this generator get a taste of these: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/
2. SVG backgrounds. These allow you to create just any gradient you wish. You can use an svg file in your CSS just like any other image. However, some browsers don't support this feature. Here's a table showing [when it's an option](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-css)

Using images is the most reliable option, while combining SVG with normal images (for these browsers that don't support SVG) seems the most flexible approach.

Comment: 1.We do alter markup in every day life, 2. Its an alternate approach, if you have javascript disabled than use normal approach, 3. I told you its no more different than overlapping two div's, that is the very easy to do. NOTE: I am not being biased but I am not convinced.

Comment: @AshwinSingh you can't convince me that altering markup for the sake of making gradients is a good thing. Markup is for semantics only (altering it is fine if it means something, like in case of inserting **content** downloaded via AJAX) but not for making something *look* as you wish. IMO, ignoring this just makes the web a huge mess.